# Using Command Line Switches to Save a PDF as Text - Can it be done?

Tags: windows, pdf, automation

I need to use command line switches to execute the 'Save as Text' command. Ideally, I want to:

1. use a command line switch to open a PDF
2. use a command line switch to convert the PDF to a text file by mimicking the 'Save as Text' command.
3. use a command line to close the PDF.

Is this possible? If so, then does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Ugh, please pay more attention to your tagging in the future.  Categorize your question.  _Don't_ try to summarize it.  Each tag should stand on it's own.

Comment: Not sure which OS you are running, but there is a tool called "pdftotext" that seems to do what you want. It's available in Linux, but there may be comparable tools for other operating systems.

Comment: I'm sorry, I neglected to mention the operating system. This is Windows.  I have heard of this tool; unfortunately buying a solution is not an option - hence we are left with building one.

Thanks though!

Comment: Not sure what "buying" means for you. pdftotext is free.

Comment: Free-ware is definitely better than purchasing, but in our environment, it would take a few weeks for this to be approved for usage at this site.  That is why the command line route would be the best - no forms to fill out, no waiting why a test team examines the product, etc.

Comment: Outch. Which software do you have available? Is there a Python (+pdftools) installation for scripting this? Otherwise, I won't be able to help.

Comment: Yes - I just checked the approved software list - Python 2.5.2 is approved

Comment: did you find the answer for this?

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try this: https://github.com/luochen1990/nodejs-easy-pdf-parser

It is a npm package and you need to install nodejs (and npm) to use it.

It can be used as a command line tool:

```
npm install -g easy-pdf-parser
pdf2text test.pdf > test.txt
```

And this tool will sort text lines by their y coordinates, so it works great at most case. And it also works well with unicode and cross platform.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use CMD; use AutoIt.  Very easy to do and takes a few lines

```
Run("file.pdf")
winwait("Adobe")
send(?);; whatever commands necessary to save as text
send("{enter}")
send("!{F4}")
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand why you'd not want to use free software (not freeware),  [pdftotext](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html) is the ideal solution.
However, if you just want to actually open and save the PDF in an automated fashion using the Windows GUI, you could use vbscript and the sendkeys command.

Just use pdftotext though, it would be much more reliable and won't cost you a whole box.

Comment: Thanks - I was thinking about doing the 'SENDKEYS' method but wanted to see if there was something quick and dirty. Yes, our environment places tight restrictions on acceptable software.  Using Python (which is approved) may also be an option.

Comment: +1 - for one should always use the google "site:http: //stackoverflow.com" <<wordToFind>> to save some 5 minutes of crap ware advertisements, because clever guys like you have posted already the answer ...

Answer (score 1):

I think the below VBscript should do the trick. It will take all .pdf files in a given folder location and save them as .txt files. One **major** bummer is it only works if your machine is not locked since it uses the SendKeys command. If anyone has a solution that works while a computer is locked, please send it my way!

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "PATH_OF_ALL_PDFS_YOU_WANT_TO_CONVERT_HERE"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)

Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile In colFiles
  extension = Mid(objFile.Name, Len(objFile.Name) - 3, 4)
  file = Mid(objFile.Name, 1, Len(objFile.Name) - 4)
  fullname = objFSO.BuildPath(objStartFolder, objFile.Name)
  fullname_txt = objFSO.BuildPath(objStartFolder, file + ".txt")

  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

  If extension = ".pdf" And Not objFSO.FileExists(fullname_txt) Then
      WScript.Echo fullname
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    WshShell.Run """" + fullname + """"
    WScript.Sleep 1000
    WshShell.SendKeys "%"
    WScript.Sleep 100
    WshShell.SendKeys "f"
    WScript.Sleep 100
    WshShell.SendKeys "h"
    WScript.Sleep 100
    WshShell.SendKeys "x"
    WScript.Sleep 300
    WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

    count = 0
    'this little step prevents the loop from moving on to the next .pdf before the conversion to .txt is complete
    Do While i = 0 And count < 100
      On Error Resume Next
      Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
      Set MyFile = fso.OpenTextFile(fullname_txt, 8)
      If Err.Number = 0 Then
        i = 1
      End If
      count = count + 1
      WScript.Sleep 20000
    Loop
  End If
Next
```

Answer (score -1):

I will also suggest `ps2ascii` for posterity. It is freely available and pre-installed on many platforms and converts a PDF to TXT quickly and easily:

- `ps2ascii my.pdf` (sends to stdout)
- or send it to an output file `ps2ascii my.pdf > my.txt`

---

For what it’s worth, `ps2ascii` is a wrapper of [ghostscript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghostscript) functionality.