# pdf saveas txt through adobe reader in cmd

Tags: vba, pdf, batch-file, excel

I have tried to do in batch command lines what I can do in Adobe Reader with the following steps: `File> Save as text`

Is it possible? I have tried the following options unsuccessfully:

```
AcroRd32.exe /t Filename

AcroRd32.exe /p Filename
```

Else, does anyone know any alternative through VBA? (without Adobe Professional edition nor alternative software).

I appreciate any help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Command Line Switches to Save a PDF as Text - Can it be done?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196148/using-command-line-switches-to-save-a-pdf-as-text-can-it-be-done)

Comment: Do you have Adobe Reader or Acrobat Standard?